# Correct place to use the word "Fathomed"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs

I have used "Fathomed" in the following sentence

> "Fathomed the issue. And solved the issue"

to mean

> "I understood the problem and I solved it"

Is this the right way to use *fathomed*?

Comment: A nerdy way would be _I grokked and subsequently solved the issue_

Comment: If the "issue" was marine or nautical in nature, that might be a clever play on the word.

Answer (score 4):

It's technically correct but quite unusual. I would be more likely to say "I grasped/understood the issue."

*Fathom* is more commonly used in the negative:  "I can't fathom why ..." or, as an adjective, "It was an unfathomable mystery."

[*Fathom*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fathom?utm_expid=53203432-7.nIZ06w4jQO6CBLpDJCQ4Mg.0&utm_referrer=http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CEQQFjAC&url=http%253A%252F%252Foxforddictionaries.com%252Fdefinition%252Fenglish%252Ffathom&ei=GMAdUqG8Da7H7Ab8wYGoBw&usg=AFQjCNHxoN6cO4ThTRumu77PFX8vFmN1rA&sig2=bgUpNXV4nlq-q3irr39o_g&bvm=bv.51156542,d.ZGU) as a noun is a measurement of water depth. You commonly hear "I got to the bottom of it", meaning that you understood something.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that *fathom* is more often used in this sense with a negative: 'I can't fathom it.'

Answer (score 0):

you can use it but It is more generally used in negative sense..

For eg.

> I never fathomed this going into the industry.
>
> What if there were no adequate explanations and the violence was so atavistic it couldn't be fathomed?
>
> While I knew these days you could do almost anything with your phone, I never fathomed masturbating was an option.